# Where's John gone? (aka Blog post onebox showing only one author while there are more)

Tags: bug, chat, blog, onebox

When a blog post is oneboxed in chat, we see only one author: ([example onebox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8613983#8613983))

[image: blog post onebox with one author]

However, [the blog post itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/11/02/go-golang-learn-fast-programming-languages) has two authors:

[image: blog post with two authors]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: super strange. On this one https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8571606  there are also two authors and the blog feed has `<dc:creator><![CDATA[Ben Popper and Medi Madelen Gwosdz]]></dc:creator>` but it looks like that is happily ignored.